# Solving : $x^2 z_x + y^2 z_y = 2xy$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Exercise :**

> Find the general integral and compute three different solutions for the PDE :
>   $$x^2 z_x + y^2 z_y = 2xy$$

**Attempt :**

The general integral is given by a function $F \in C^1$ : $F(u_1,u_2) = 0$, where $u_1$ and $u_2$ are the integral curves, calculated by the differential problem : 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2xy}$$
But then I am at loss on how to calculate the general solutions asked.

Also, for $u_1$ and $u_2$ :

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2} \implies u_1 = \frac{y-x}{xy}$$

but I am also unable to grasp a calculation for $u_2$.

Any help and explanation about the general solutions and $u_2$ will be greatly appreciated as this is a new subject I am getting in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your result
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y^2} \implies c_1 = \frac{y-x}{xy}$$
You can deduce y as a function of x
$$\implies y=\frac x {1-c_1x}$$

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2xy}$$
$$\implies  \frac{2y\mathrm{d}x}{x} = dz$$
$$\implies  \frac{2\mathrm{d}x}{{1-c_1x}} = dz$$
$$\implies  \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{{x-\frac 1 {c_1}}} = -\frac {c_1}2\int dz$$

Which is easy to integrate...

Comment: Thanks for yet again another integral trick. How would one continue into calculating the general solutions though ?

Comment: You have a second constant $c_2$

Comment: I have calculated $u_1, u_2$ thus the general integral truly is $F(u_1,u_2) = 0$. No problem with that. But what about finding three different general solutions ?

Comment: I don't know what they mean by that...is it a book that you are studying in ?? @Rebellos

Comment: Yes ! "Introduction to Partial Differential Equations with Applications" by Zachmanoglou.

Comment: I didnt knoow that book...it must be interesting...

Comment: Pretty hard to say the truth.

Comment: You are doing a good job and with practise and time you will be really good at it @Rebellos

Comment: Thanks a lot for the good words and especially the nice help !

Answer (score 1):

The hint "finding three different general solutions" it could mean the solutions of
$$
ds=\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{dy}{y^2}=\frac{dz}{2xy}
$$
as functions of $s$. As $x(s)=\frac{x_0}{1-sx_0}$, $y(s)=\frac{y_0}{1-sy_0}$ one gets
$$
\frac{dz}{ds}=\frac{2x_0y_0}{(1-sx_0)(1-sy_0)}=\frac{2x_0y_0}{x_0-y_0}\left(\frac{x_0}{1-sx_0}-\frac{y_0}{1-sy_0}\right)
$$
so that
$$
z(s)=z_0+\frac{2x_0y_0}{x_0-y_0}\left(\ln(1-sy_0)-\ln(1-sx_0)\right)
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for a clarification at that hint given at the exercise ! It probably means that, since it also asks to find some restrictions about the three solutions yielded.

Comment: By the way, I would like to ask, how do you yield the expressions for $x(s)$ and $y(s)$ ?

Comment: This are the standard solutions for $\dot x=x^2$, $x^{-2}\dot x=1$, $x_0^{-1}-x(s)^{-1}=s$ etc.

Comment: But shouldn't it be $x(s) = \frac{1}{c_1 - s}$ let's say ?

Comment: Yes, and if you insert some initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ you get $c_1=x_0^{-1}$  and so my solution form.